# Running Scrapy daily and tracking changes in the data

Tags: scrapy

So I've written my first scraper with Scrapy and I'm having some trouble with the next steps. I want to run the scraper daily, probably with cron, and track the changes in the values I've scraped. When I export to a json or csv file, then run the scraper again, the new data gets dumped into the same file. Is there a way to make each scrape export into a separate file? Any insight would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

tell scrapy the name of the file to write to using `-o`

```
$ scrapy crawl -h | grep output=
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
```

you can use current date as file name like:

```
$ scrapy crawl <spider-name> -t json/csv -o $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
```